# How to plot label.new() under double if blocks in pine script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I want to plot the label with the following pine script that I can record it when I export the data and make an alert when the label comes out:

```
if array.size(zigzagpivots) > i_loopback * 2 + 2
    lastConfirmedPivot = array.get(zigzagpivots, 1)
    lastConfirmedPivotBar = array.get(zigzagpivotbars, 1)
    lastConfirmedPivotDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, 1)
    if ta.change(lastConfirmedPivot)
        for i = 1 to i_loopback - 1 by 1
            iDir = array.get(zigzagpivotdirs, i) % 2
            iDir := iDir % 2 == 0 ? iDir / 2 : iDir
            for j = i + 2 to i_loopback + 1 by 2
                iPivotPattern = iDir * array.get(zigzagpivots, i) > iDir * array.get(zigzagpivots, j) ? iDir * 2 : iDir
                pattern := pattern + str.tostring(iDir)
                pattern
        lastIndex := array.indexof(patternArray, pattern)
        if lastIndex != -1
            randomColor = f_random_color(70)
            lastBarIndex = array.get(patternBarArray, lastIndex)
            lastOccurance = time[bar_index - lastBarIndex]

            lastTime = str.tostring(year(lastOccurance), '0000') + '/' + str.tostring(month(lastOccurance), '00') + '/' + str.tostring(dayofmonth(lastOccurance), '00') + (timeframe.isintraday ? '-' + str.tostring(hour(lastOccurance), '00') + ':' + str.tostring(minute(lastOccurance), '00') + ':' + str.tostring(second(lastOccurance), '00') : '')
            yloc = lastConfirmedPivotDir > 0 ? yloc.abovebar : yloc.belowbar
            style = lastConfirmedPivotDir > 0 ? label.style_triangledown : label.style_triangleup
            label.new(lastConfirmedPivotBar, close, text='', color=randomColor, style=style, tooltip='⬅ ' + lastTime, yloc=yloc)
            plot(lastConfirmedPivotBar)
        array.unshift(patternArray, pattern)
        array.unshift(patternBarArray, bar_index)
```

However, it comes out with the an error:

```
Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Where is the `plot()` call in your example?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the updated script. It should be under the code:  ```label.new(lastConfirmedPivotBar, close, text='', color=randomColor, style=style, tooltip='⬅ ' + lastTime, yloc=yloc)```

Comment: Edit your question and add your code there please.

Comment: The code is edited

Comment: What is `lastConfirmedPivotBar`? Is it a bar index? How do you plan to use it?